# server taking too much time to start a port

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, http-request

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to install Laravel framework. In this purpose I have run this code in terminal:

> php artisan serve

After waiting for 4-5 minutes I got this response:

> Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
>
> [Tue May 26 13:19:40 2015] 127.0.0.1:44800 [200]: /favicon.ico
>
> [Tue May 26 13:19:40 2015] 127.0.0.1:44801 [200]: /favicon.ico

After waiting for more than 10 minutes I got no more response although terminal is working.

Does it really take that much time? Or what's wrong?

Comment: Is the script constantly needing to run in background in order for laravel server to be running/available? If so, you don't want it to exit, but you may want to have it run in the background or as a service.

Comment: does your laravel application also takes long to load?

Comment: Usually when a server takes too long to start - it's either a DNS problem (trying to resolve own name) or `SO_REUSEADDR` option is missing when trying to bind to a listening socket (a port).

Comment: no, laravel is not running

Comment: then, what can I do? although port 8000 has been started, http://localhost:8000/  shows that, Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: You need to stop the server and run this command which specifies the public directory `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` as the root document root

Comment: you can also cd into your `laravelProject/public` then 
`php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: good. please confirm if it took long? is the starting processing still slow?

Comment: its working well, but i need to run treminal in background, if i exit terminal, port 8000 is automatically stopped, do i need to run it in background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> then, what can I do? although port 8000 has been started,
>   localhost:8000 shows that, Sorry, the page you are looking for could
>   not be found.

You need to stop the server and run this command which specifies the public directory `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` as the root document root

or
you can also cd into your laravelProject/public then `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: How does this work? Doing this creates a listening function and it must be quit to resume use of the terminal.